# How do I set attibutes of a component from an Angular directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to write an attribute directive that will set the attributes of a host Angular component. I have seen examples that are setting the attributes of native host elements e.g class. I want to use this directive to set the properties of the ngx-spinner component so that I don't have to repeat myself everywhere that I use the spinner. I've tried using the @HostBinding() directive e.g.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSpinner]',
})
export class SpinnerDirective {
  @HostBinding('type')
  type = 'ball-spin-clockwise-fade';

  constructor() {}
}
```

But this does not seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried with `@HostBinding('attr.type')` instead?

Comment: @user776686 that didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: Maybe accessing the `NgxSpinnerComponent` on the directive `@Host` will help? `constructor(@Host() spinner: NgxSpinnerComponent) {spinner.type = 'ball-spin-clockwise-fade'}`. It won't of course change the type during its lifetime when used this way.

Comment: For my purpose, that solution works. Thanks. BTW, where is the documentation for that decorator because I couldn't find it at angular.io

Comment: TBH I would not desperately look out for Angular docs, as they often fail. This article should get you started: https://indepth.dev/posts/1063/a-curious-case-of-the-host-decorator-and-element-injectors-in-angular